# Knockout bindingHandler causes pureComputed evaluation delay

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I found that my bindingHandler causes unexpected pureComputed evaluation delay.

[Demo here](https://codepen.io/lzl124631x/pen/mdyWgNV)

## Without binding handler

Without binding handler (simply comment the HTML out), I see the following log:

```
In subscription, new value is (newName), nameComputed is (newNameComputed)
```

As you can see, in the subscription, the computed was evaluated to the latest value.

## With binding handler

With binding handler, I see the following log:

```
Evaluation in bindingHandler oldNameComputed
In subscription, new value is (newName), nameComputed is (oldNameComputed)
Evaluation in bindingHandler newNameComputed
```

As you can see, in the subscription, the computed was still using the old value (oldNameComputed), and in the next evaluation it's evaluated to latest value (newNameComputed)

## Question

This is unexpected to me -- adding the binding handler changes the evaluation behavior.

- How to explain this? Is this a bug or expected?
- How to work around this? Do I have not to use pureComputed but use observable for `nameComputed` and set it in subscription on `name`?

---

## Update 12/26/2019

Adding a bit context. My `nameComputed` is actually `nameError` which processes the `name` and detects whether the input is allowed or has errors (e.g. no special character, nonempty, max length etc).

In the subscription, I wanted to do some ajax calls if there is no name error. So I looked at the value of `nameError` and only fires the requests if there is no error.

But with the binding handler, my `nameError` check is outdated.

Yes, I do have the latest `name` value in the subscription, but I need to call the name error check function again to get the latest `nameError` value instead of directly using `nameError` computed value.

Comment: I see what you mean (same thing happens when you use one of the default binding handlers like `text`), but I'm a bit confused as to why it's a problem? You could (and should) use the parameter in the subscription to determine the current value of `name`. If you for some reason want to get the latest value of `nameComputed` whenever it mutates then you can just subscribe to that instead.

Comment: @BrotherWoodrow I added some context in the question. Hope it help explaining my case

Answer (score 1):

**Credit to mbest in [Github Issue](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/2509)**

The first section in the [pure computed documentation](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-pure.html) describes its two states. The difference you see in behavior is because the pure computed is in a different state. Without the binding handler, it is in the sleeping state, and with the binding handler, it is in the awake state.

It is normal that a subscription can run while state is being updated, and thus not all computed observables have been updated with the latest value. The main way to work around this is use deferred updates. If you set `ko.options.deferUpdates = true;`, you will get the results you want.

---

I might not go in this route for now because I'm working on a big project and don't want to introduce this global level change for now.